# How to pass data from page endpoints to a layout component in Sveltekit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

A [page endpoint](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#endpoints-page-endpoints) is a convenient way to handle requests in Sveltekit, which also makes it a useful place to handle the errors that can occur, as in:

**src/routes/items.js**

```
export async function POST({ request }) {
  const [errors, item] = await db.create(request)
 
  if (errors) {
    return {
      status: 400,
      body: { errors }
    }
  }
}
```

Displaying the error might not be made in `src/routes/items.svelte` however. Often you want them to be shown on the top of the page, or as a [toast notification](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11998/what-is-a-toast-notification). The place for these would be in a layout component:

**src/routes/__layout.svelte**

```
<header>
  <Errors />
</header>

<main>
  <slot></slot>
</main>
```

It's quite boilerplatey to have code in every route component that checks for errors and passes them on to another component, so is there a more svelte way to do this? The load function is being changed for 1.0, and I'd really like to keep it simple with everything done in a page endpoint.

Comment: Are those async requests? What does the calling code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by using a cookie that gets passed on to `locals` and then `session` for display in any component.

It was a bit harder than expected, especially to make it work both with SSR and on the client, so I have packaged up the solution in a library here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sveltekit-flash-message

Answer (score 1):

The best practice to load data from an endpoint to the layout would be to throw it in the $data.stuff by using the load function. But that's the old way...

Since the update from file based routing to directory based routing the `$page.stuff` global variable became `$page.stuff`. So you'll need to make sure your routing is directory based in a strucutre like this

```
 src
 └  routes
    ├  +page.svelte
    ├  +layout.svelte
    ├  +error.svelte
    └  items
       ├  +page.svelte
       └  +page.js
```

So the current best practice to send data from your endpoint to layout would be to start by loading your data in your `+data.js` by using the load function. Will probably look something like this:

```
/** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */

async function POST({ request }) {
const [errors, item] = await db.create(request)

if (errors) {
  export function load() {
    return {
      status: 400,
      body: { errors }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how you're pulling the data from your database but the important part is to throw it into the

```
export function load() {
  return {
    `throw your error here`
    status: 400,
    body: { errors }
  }
}
```

Then on your +layout.svelte simply import the $page.data variable and define new variables for your loaded errors like this

```
<script>
  import { page } from '$app/stores';

  let status = $page.data.status,
      body = $page.data.body;

</script>
```

Sources:

https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/5774#discussioncomment-3292693
https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load

Comment: Just a slight addendum, the $ before page makes it reactive. So whenever the state of $page changes it should react globally.